# How do I get rid of the default wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper, conky

I changed my wallpaper, but the default wallpaper still shows up before logging into my profile and after logging out of my profile. It's also being used as the background for my conky.

If anyone could help me with the conky problem as well, I would greatly appreciate it.

[image: Here's an image of what's happening with the conky]

Here's my .conkyrc file:

```
    #====================================
#   Conky Settings
#====================================
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes


#====================================
#   Window Specifications
#====================================
gap_x 0
gap_y 0
alignment middle_middle

minimum_size 600 380
maximum_width 600

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0

#border_margin 0
#border_inner_margin 0
#border_outer_margin 0


#====================================
#   Graphics Settings
#====================================
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no


#====================================
#   Text Settings
#====================================
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont sans serif:size=10
override_utf8_locale yes
imlib_cache_size 0


#====================================
#   Color Scheme
#====================================
default_color FFFFFF

color0 FFFFFF   # clock
color1 FFFFFF   # date
color2 FFFFFF   # current temperature
color3 FFFFFF   # high tempratures
color4 FFFFFF   # low tempratures
color5 FFFFFF   # days


#====================================
#   Icon Sources
#====================================
template0 ~/.conky-vision-icons/FFFFFF  # today
template1 ~/.conky-vision-icons/FFFFFF  # +1day
template2 ~/.conky-vision-icons/FFFFFF  # +2days
template3 ~/.conky-vision-icons/FFFFFF  # +3days
template4 ~/.conky-vision-icons/FFFFFF  # +4days


#====================================
#   WOEID (Where On Earth ID)
#====================================
template7 22664084


#====================================
#   Temp Unit (c = Celsius, f = Fahrenheit)
#====================================
template8 c


#====================================
#   Language (e.g. es_ES.UTF-8)
#====================================
template9  # leave empty for locale


###################################################
###################################################


TEXT
#----------------------------------------
#   CURL
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=${template7}&u=${template8}" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}\
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Clock
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:weight=Light:size=96}${color0}\
${alignc}${time %H:%M}\
${font}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Date
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:weight=Light:size=28}${color1}\
${voffset 30}\
${alignc}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date +"%A, %B %d"}\
${font}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Current Temperature
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:size=18}${color2}\
${voffset 36}\
${goto 60}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°\
${font}${color}\
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   High Temperatures
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:size=12}${color3}\
${goto 164}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°\
\
${goto 272}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°\
\
${goto 378}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°\
\
${goto 484}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°\
${font}${color}\
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Low Temparatures
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:size=12}${color4}\
${voffset 52}\
${goto 218}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°\
${goto 324}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°\
${goto 430}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°\
${goto 536}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°\
${font}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Day Names
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${font Poiret One:size=14}${color5}\
${voffset 20}\
${goto 76}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date +%^a}\
${goto 182}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +1day +%^a}\
${goto 288}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +2days +%^a}\
${goto 394}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +3days +%^a}\
${goto 500}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +4days +%^a}\
${font}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Weather Icons
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${execi 300 cp -f ${template0}/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 72,268 -s 32x32}\
\
${execi 300 cp -f ${template1}/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 178,268 -s 32x32}\
\
${execi 300 cp -f ${template2}/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 284,268 -s 32x32}\
\
${execi 300 cp -f ${template3}/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4').png ~/.cache/weather-4.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-4.png -p 390,268 -s 32x32}\
\
${execi 300 cp -f ${template4}/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5').png ~/.cache/weather-5.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-5.png -p 496,268 -s 32x32}\
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change the wallpaper from the system settings. If you want a custom wallpaper, copy the image to: `~/.local/share/backgrounds/` and then change it from the system settings.

Comment: That's what I did, but it still appears in the login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greeter is supposed to show the currently selected user's wallpaper. If you are using a custom wallpaper and it does not work, it is most likely caused by a permission issue; The wallpaper file has to be available for everyone to read. Check the file's permissions with `ls -lisa /path/to/file`. If the permissions do not show up like `rw-r--r--`, you'll need to add them (for example via `chmod o+r /path/to/file`). You can find more information regarding permissions [in this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes).

As the other answer indicates, you can edit the file `/etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf` with administrative privileges and change the following line to choose a different default wallpaper. You will need to un-comment the line (remove the `#` in front) as well.

```
 #default-wallpaper=/usr/share/backgrounds/elementaryos-default
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! I did everything that embik suggested, and then restarted. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf
```

Find `#default-wallpaper=/usr/share/backgrounds/elementaryos-default`

Delete the # and change the directory?